# Status is not changing API in laravel

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I try to build an API for an android app it shows complaint details when an employee enter remarks of the complaint then change the status into on working from a drop-down menu in the app. But it throws an error like this.i use postman to run the API

The status is not changing and remarks entry is not working

"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: update complaints inner join monitorings on monitorings.complaint_id = complaints.temp_complaint_id set 0 = complaints.root_cause, 1 = monitorings.status, updated_at = 2018-07-17 12:35:27)"

```
 public function complaint_onworking(Request $request)
        {
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'rootcause' => 'required',

            ]);
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return $this->sendError('Validation Error.', $validator->errors());
            }
    //
            $compid = $request->input('comp_id');
            $user_id = $request->input('user_id');
            $rootcause = $request->input('rootcasue');

                $onworkrequest = Complaint::join('monitorings',
        'monitorings.complaint_id', '=', 'complaints.temp_complaint_id')
        ->select([
            'monitorings.complaint_id', 'monitorings.current_user_id','complaints.root_cause'
        ])
        ->where([
            ['complaints.temp_complaint_id', '=', $compid],
            ['monitorings.current_user_id', '=', $user_id]
        ])
        ->get();
    //        return $onworkrequest;

            foreach ($onworkrequest as $onworking) {

                if ($onworking) {

                   $onwork =Complaint::join('monitorings','monitorings.complaint_id', '=', 'complaints.temp_complaint_id')
            ->where([['complaints.temp_complaint_id', '=', $compid], ['monitorings.current_user_id', '=', $user_id]])
                ->update([['monitorings.root_cause', '=', $rootcause],['monitorings.status', '=', 1]]);

    //                $cmpt=array('routcause' =>$rootcause);
                           $success['routcause']=$onwork->root_cause;

                    return $this->sendResponse($success, 'Complaint is in onworking');
                } else {
                    $success = "";
                    return $this->sendResponse($success, 'No change in status');
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: so have you check your if condition is satisfied or not?

Comment: i think so @SachinAghera

Comment: please try to dd() inside if condition.

Comment: let me try @SachinAghera

Comment: i throws same error @SachinAghera

Comment: Where you use  `stripos()`?

Comment: i am not using stripos(),i can't figure it out where it comes from @VaheShak

Comment: can you please show me what you get in $onworkrequest?

Comment: your arrays in select seems to strange.

Comment: yea it's not correct i think i am not sure what i was i doing @VaheShak

Comment: [
    {
        "complaint_id": "1",
        "current_user_id": "1",
        "root_cause": ""
    }
]                                                                                                                                  This what i get from the query @VaheShak

Comment: Now the error changed "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: update `complaints` inner join `monitorings` on `monitorings`.`complaint_id` = `complaints`.`temp_complaint_id` set `0` = complaints.root_cause, `1` = monitorings.status, `updated_at` = 2018-07-17 12:35:27)" @VaheShak @Sachin Aghera

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things I spotted in your Eloquent query.

`Model::update` should be passed an array of fields to be updated as keys and values to update with.

```
/**
 * Update the model in the database.
 *
 * @param  array  $attributes
 * @param  array  $options
 * @return bool
 */
public function update(array $attributes = [], array $options = [])
```

[See Model::update method signature](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L549) / [Examples](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/tests/Integration/Database/EloquentUpdateTest.php)

```
$onwork = Complaint:::join(
                 'monitoring', 
                 'monitoring.complaint_id', '=', 'complaints.temp_complaint_id')
             ->where([
              'complaints.temp_complaint_id' => $compid,
              'monitoring.primary_user_id' => $user_id
          ])
          ->update([
               'monitoring.routcause' => $rootcause,
               'monitoring.status' => 1
          ]);
```

Also, [See Model::select method signature](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L219)

```
$onworkrequest = Complaint:join(
                     'monitoring', 
                     'monitoring.complaint_id', '=', 'complaints.temp_complaint_id')
                 ->select([
                     /* THIS ISN'T RIGHT 
                     ['monitoring.complaint_id', '=', $request->input('comp_id')],
                     ['monitoring.primary_user_id', '=', $request->input('user_id')],
                     ['routcause', '=', $request->input('rootcause')] */ 
                 ])
                 ->where([
                     ['complaints.temp_complaint_id', '=', $compid], 
                     ['monitoring.primary_user_id', '=', $user_id]
                 ])
                 ->get();
```

For the select query, you either pass an array of columns to select or arguments of columns to select. e.g.

```
...
->select('monitoring.complaint_id', 'monitoring.primary_user_id', 'routcause')
```

There are more examples of the [`Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L219) API in the [tests here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/tests/Database/DatabaseQueryBuilderTest.php#L123).

Comment: Let me change it @Oluwafemi Sule

Comment: Now i get this error "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: update `complaints` inner join `monitorings` on `monitorings`.`complaint_id` = `complaints`.`temp_complaint_id` set `0` = complaints.root_cause, `1` = monitorings.status, `updated_at` = 2018-07-17 12:35:27)" @Oluwafemi Sule

Comment: That's a weird error but helpful one. I can't reason why the query is `...set 0 = complaints.root_cause and 1=monitorings.status`. It should be `...set  complaints.root_cause=0 and monitorings.status=1`. You can update your question with the new exception so that anyone can help

Comment: will do that,i think  i am close to get output

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the error and works fine.there was a problem in the update query and I fixed, thanks for the help guys really appreciate it

```
$onwork=Complaint::where([['temp_complaint_id','=',$compid],['status','!=','5']])
                        ->update(['root_cause'=>$rootcause,
                                  'status'=>'7']);
```